# How to give an alternative value when there isn't enough data for qcut

Tags: python, pandas

I'm looking to create column "priceCategory" that gives either "low", "medium" or "high" based on a products price and category. The code below should do exactly that.
Although it is possible a category has less than 3 products with unique prices. So after throwing away the duplicates with “duplicates=’drop’”, there won’t be enough bins compared to labels. I’m looking to change its value to “medium” if there isn’t enough data to properly do the qcut.
I’ve done some research and found similar problems, but none where there could be both not enough data and had to be done in a loop (per category).

```
for i in products_df['categoryName'].unique():
        products_df.loc[products_df['categoryName']==i,'priceCategory'] = pd.qcut(products_df['price'][products_df['categoryName']==i],3,labels=['low','medium','high'], duplicates='drop')
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a work-around by checking how many unique values there are in price for each category. It’s less efficient than I first hoped it’d be, but it seems to work. Feel free to add your thoughts to this if you think there is a more efficient way to do this.

```
for i in products_df['categoryName'].unique():
    #get amount of unique values in price for each category
    amountUnique = len(products_df[products_df['categoryName'] == i]['price'].unique())
    if(amountUnique > 1):
        products_df.loc[products_df['categoryName']==i,'priceCategory'] = pd.qcut(products_df['price'][products_df['categoryName']==i],3,labels=['low','medium','high'], duplicates='drop')
    else:
        products_df.loc[products_df['categoryName']==i,'priceCategory'] = 'medium'
```